# Where is my MISTAKE in my solution?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics

This is the second time I keep asking the SAME thing. I hope I finally understand.

The question is as shown below:
[image]

with its answer:
[image]

Below is my answer for part a. PLEASE tell me where is my mistake!
[image]

FYI the accurate answer is that both are conducting. But **what is wrong with my assumption**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *This is the second time I keep asking the SAME thing* Asking the same thing TWICE isn't appreciated here.

Comment: What both are conduncting? What is this question even originally about?

Comment: @ Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy I assumed that D1 is off and D2 is on. Where is my mistake?

Comment: "The question is as shown below" - no it isn't, that's just a circuit diagram. What is the actual question?

Comment: The Anode of D1 is **GROUNDED** in schematic 1, it is **NOT** in schematic 2. What does that mean for the voltage on node **B**?

Comment: @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy I am sorry I updated the question. Where is my mistake??

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes I assumed that D1 is off i.e. not conducting is this assumption wrong? if yes why?

Comment: With your assumptions, you get a result that V = -10/3V. Since D2 is on, that means the voltage at B is also -10/3V. Since the voltage at B is lower than GND, this would imply that D1 is forward-biased. Your assumption was that D1 is off, but your calculations show that it should be on (forward-biased).

Comment: @brhans No. for D1 to be ON the anode voltage minus the cathode voltage must be zero. Any other voltage difference it will be in cutoff region. Am I right or not?

Comment: For D1 to be OFF, the voltage at node B must be higher than GND. This is not the case, thus your assumption is incorrect. Try the calculation again with another assumption.

Comment: No. For a diode to be forward-biased (on) the anode must be at a higher voltage than the cathode. Your D1 anode is at 0V. Your calculation puts the cathode at -10/3V. So the anode is at a higher voltage than the cathode - therefore the diode should be forward-biased, and your initial assumption was wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the voltage is assumed zero Confusing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541902/why-the-voltage-is-assumed-zero-confusing)

Comment: @Finbarr That's MY question. I AM A SLOW LEARNER. Please forgive my understanding guys.

Comment: I know it's your question, and you've accepted the answer to it. If you don't understand the answer you should ask there for clarification.

Comment: @Finbarr I didn't know that. Actually I revisited the same question and got stuck. Now I understand my mistake. My mistake is that I thought "wrongfully" that an ideal diode will conduct ONLY if the voltage are equal. Which was wrong, if the anode is higher IT WILL CONDUCT equalizing the voltage across it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the accurate answer is that both are conducting. But what is wrong
> with my assumption.*

There's nothing wrong with your assumption; it's just an assumption that tests a hypotheses. So, you make an assumption and you find that for an ideal diode, the voltage at V is -3.333 volts. The assumption you made, in effect, disconnects D1: -

[image]

It's what you do next with the voltage being -3.333 volts that is important - you TEST that initial assumption.

So, if V = -3.333 volts then (with ideal diodes), the voltage at the cathode of D1 is also -3.333 volts and this cannot be possibly true (because it means D1 would certainly be conducting).

Conclusion: the initial assumption is false. But, it's certainly not incorrect to make what is proven to be a false assumption - this is part of the process of getting to the truth.

Answer (score -1):

With schematic 4.6a shown , both diodes will always conduct and the output is 1/3 of the 20V span above -10V= 20/3-30/3= -10/3V

Then correct for Vf =0.6V by lowering output.

In b) it is 2/3 of 20V span above -10V or 40/3-30/3 = 10/3 V

Comment: PLEASE tell me where is my mistake. I am trying to understand you are you saying because the anode voltage of D1 is ZERO and since the voltage at the cathode of D1 is negative that this is NOT POSSIBLE?? because D1 will conduct?

Comment: Both diodes are always forward biased